# Get leaf nodes - XML parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to parse an XML and get all the leaf nodes ?

```
<root>
<emp>
<name>abc<name>
<age>12</age>
</emp>
<dept>
<branch>cse</branch>
</dept>
</root>
```

My output should be 
name
age
branch

Comment: Check this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/).

Comment: check here http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Your example XML has an error: It should be `<name>abc</name>` not `<name>abc<name>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this XPath expression to find alle elements which have no other elements as childs: `//*[count(./*) = 0]`.

```
try {
  final Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("input.xml");
  final XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//*[count(./*) = 0]");
  final NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    final Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
    System.out.println(el.getNodeName());
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result is

```
name
age
branch
```

Comment: OP appears to want the tag names, not the content of the tags.

Comment: @vanje: What changes should I make to this code, If i wanted the the tag name and values that have attributes.

Answer (score 0):

reading xml is quite simple.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile{

public static void main (String argv []){
try {

DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("book.xml"));

// normalize text representation
doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);

for(int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength() ; s++){


Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
if(firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode; 

//-------
NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);

NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
System.out.println("First Name : " + ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

//------- 
NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
Element lastNameElement = (Element)lastNameList.item(0);

NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
System.out.println("Last Name : " + ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

//----
NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("age");
Element ageElement = (Element)ageList.item(0);

NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
System.out.println("Age : " + ((Node)textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

//------


}//end of if clause


}//end of for loop with s var


}catch (SAXParseException err) {
System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());

}catch (SAXException e) {
Exception x = e.getException ();
((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();

}catch (Throwable t) {
t.printStackTrace ();
}
//System.exit (0);

}//end of main


}
```

Comment: i know to parse the xml. I just wanted to get the leaf nodes alone. How can i get that

Comment: for any given xml, it must return only the leaf nodes

Answer (score 0):

try this code... i saved your xml code in e.xml in desktop folder and get name and age and branch from your xml

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/devteam/Desktop/e.xml"));

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        System.out.println("*************************");
        String expression = "/root/emp/name";
        String exp1="/root/emp/age";
        String exp2="/root/dept/branch";
        System.out.println(expression);
        String name = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
        System.out.println(exp1);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(exp1);
        String age = xPath.compile(exp1).evaluate(xmlDocument);
        System.out.println(age);
        String branch = xPath.compile(exp2).evaluate(xmlDocument);
        System.out.println(branch);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

**output**:

```
*************************
/root/emp/name
/root/emp/age
abc
/root/emp/age
12
cse
```

Comment: But this should work for any XML. I cannot  hard code the Xpath like this

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling with this problem too for an upcoming task at work and after a while I realised that I can check the .getChildNodes().getLength() property of a node.

e.g.

if we use the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831530/getting-all-the-tags-in-an-xml-file-using-java) question as a basis, then we can do the following once we have an element:

```
Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
if(element.getChildNodes().getLength()==1){ //returns a list
   System.out.println(element.getNodeName() +":"+element.getTextContent());
}
```

It appears that leaf nodes have only one child (their corresponding closing XML tag), hence `element.getChildNodes().getLength()` will return a list of size 1 for leaf nodes, and >1 for nodes with children.